# Pasar datos de una consulta sql a variables java

Tags: java, mysql, variables

He realizado una consulta para saber el nombre de las columnas de una tabla en una base de datos phpmyadmin, el problema es que esa consulta me la devuelve en una columna y quiero pasar cada fila de esa consulta a una variable.

```
try {
            Connection gg = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/information_schema", "root", "");
            Statement st = gg.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT column_name FROM columns WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA <> 'information_schema' AND table_name = 'data' AND ordinal_position >= 1 AND ordinal_position <= 11 ORDER BY ordinal_position";);

                while (rs.next()) {
                    TituloB = (rs.getString(1));
                    D1B = (rs.getString(2));
                    D2B = (rs.getString(3));
                    D3B = (rs.getString(4));
                    D4B = (rs.getString(5));
                    D5B = (rs.getString(6));
                    D6B = (rs.getString(7));
                    D7B = (rs.getString(8));
                    D8B = (rs.getString(9));
                    D9B = (rs.getString(10));
                    D10B = (rs.getString(11));
                }
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el nombre de cada columna se encuentre en una variable diferente?

Comment: Y si en vez de obtenerlos como columnas (que es lo que intentas y no va a funcionar porque tu resultado tiene UNA columna), iteras sobre los resultados y los vas asignando a la estructura de datos que desees usar?

Comment: @Alfabravo, sé que lo que estoy haciendo está mal, el problema es que no sé como hacerlo bien. XD De mysql sé bastante poco y es para una cosa que he de presentar. el caso es que esas variables son el título de diferentes JLabel que recogen unos datos de unos JTextField.

Comment: Si tienes certeza de que el resultado llega siempre en el orden que quieres, pues sólo es que el while se haga sobre `rs.hasNext()` y asignes el `rs.getString(1)` a un array, arraylist o lo que prefieras en la siguiente posición libre, sin mucha mente. Después ya podrás tomar esos elementos y ponérselos a tus JLabel como prefieras, leyendo el array o lo que hayas poblado con tu resultado. Busca ejemplos de cómo iterar un resultSet, hay muchos! No te atasques con que DEBAS asignar directamente del rs a tus variables; sólo te vas a complicar innecesariamente.

Comment: @Alfabravo, ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

hay dos formas de hacerlo, primero analicemos tu código

```
            while (rs.next()) {
                TituloB = (rs.getString(1));
                D1B = (rs.getString(2));
                D2B = (rs.getString(3));
                D3B = (rs.getString(4));
                D4B = (rs.getString(5));
                D5B = (rs.getString(6));
                D6B = (rs.getString(7));
                D7B = (rs.getString(8));
                D8B = (rs.getString(9));
                D9B = (rs.getString(10));
                D10B = (rs.getString(11));
            }
    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }""
```

lo que estas haciendo aquí es asignar cada nombre de columna que te obtiene como resultado a una variable D1B,D2B,etc para usarlos puedes hacer referencias directamente a esas variables ya que contienen los nombres que necesitas.

También puedes declarar los nombres de tus variables como

```
String NombreColumna1, NombreColumna2;
```

y en tu while en lugar de asignar las variables D1B asignar NombreColumna1 quedaría algo así

```
String NombreColumna1, NombreColumna2,NombreColumna3,NombreColumna4,NombreColumna5,NombreColumna6,NombreColumna7,NombreColumna8,NombreColumna9,NombreColumna10;

            while (rs.next()) {
                TituloB = (rs.getString(1));
                NombreColumna1 = (rs.getString(2));
                NombreColumna2 = (rs.getString(3));
                NombreColumna3 = (rs.getString(4));
                NombreColumna4 = (rs.getString(5));
                NombreColumna5 = (rs.getString(6));
                NombreColumna6 = (rs.getString(7));
                NombreColumna7 = (rs.getString(8));
                NombreColumna8 = (rs.getString(9));
                NombreColumna9 = (rs.getString(10));
                NombreColumna10 = (rs.getString(11));
            }
    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }""
```

y con eso ya los tendrías asignados, pero la forma mas apropiada de hacerlo es declarar un arreglo, del tamaño de tu resultSet y asignar el resultado a cada indice del arreglo

```
String NombresColumnas[]=new String[10];
while (rs.next()) {
            TituloB = (rs.getString(1));
            NombresColumnas[0] = (rs.getString(2));
            NombresColumnas[1] = (rs.getString(3));
            NombresColumnas[2] = (rs.getString(4));
            NombresColumnas[3] = (rs.getString(5));
            NombresColumnas[4] = (rs.getString(6));
            NombresColumnas[5] = (rs.getString(7));
            NombresColumnas[6] = (rs.getString(8));
            NombresColumnas[7] = (rs.getString(9));
            NombresColumnas[8] = (rs.getString(10));
            NombresColumnas[9] = (rs.getString(11));
        }
} catch (SQLException throwables) {
    throwables.printStackTrace();
}""
```